# Malfunction of a jQuery slideToggle() implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a problem with the following setup:

I have a button that is inside a `nav` element.

```
<nav id="navbuttons">
    <button type = "button" id="projectsMenu" onclick="slideProjects()">Projects</button>
</nav>
```

which should slide in/out the following `nav` element when clicked:

```
<nav id="projects">
    We're projects
</nav>
```

To do this, I'm using the following JavaScript/jQuery function:

```
function slideProjects(){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#projectsMenu").click(function(){
                                $("#projects").slideToggle("slow");
                        });
                });
        }
```

This causes eratic behavior of the button and the secondary nav (which has more stuff in it than "We're projects", but they're just examples of the same thing I'm asking about). The button has to be clicked twice in order to get the second `nav` to show, and even then, it "winks" at you (it slides down, slides up, then slides down again, sometimes multiple times).

From what I understand/have been told, I have this problem because there are too many "onclick" event handlers on in the process, which brings a need for multiple clicks like I mentioned earlier. If I remove `onclick` from the html element (I was told it was deprecated), it doesn't seem to listen to the button. Is this correct, and what do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be just

```
<nav id="navbuttons">
    <button type="button" id="projectsMenu">Projects</button>
</nav>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#projectsMenu").click(function () {
        $("#projects").stop(true).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gpLwr/)

because in your case, the actual `slideToggle` code is not executed in the first click... in the `slideProjects` method you are registering a click handler which is sliding the element. Instead you can just use the dom ready handler to add a click handler to the `projectsMenu` element and there is no need to have a `onclick` handler.

Comment: When I load the page and click the button, nothing occurs. 

Does it make a difference if the JavaScript is in a separate file?